Location of Chrome and chromedriver in Jupyter Notebook using Selenium
I am trying to scrape a website with a python notebook using Jupyter but I allways find some trouble with the Chrome and chromedriver location. I am using a Linux WSL in a Windows PC, and it is messy when it comes to locations. I tried several codes, even when Selenium 4.6 says it does not need any chromedriver.
I need to find out the proper code to scrape with selenium in jupyter notebook using Chrome
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.common.selenium_manager:Selenium Manager binary found at: /home/scaride/.pyenv/versions/taxifare-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/linux/selenium-manager
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.common.selenium_manager:Executing process: /home/scaride/.pyenv/versions/taxifare-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/linux/selenium-manager --browser chrome --debug --language-binding python --output json
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.common.selenium_manager:chromedriver not found in PATH
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.common.selenium_manager:chrome not found in PATH
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.common.selenium_manager:chrome not found in the system
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.common.selenium_manager:Required browser: chrome 124.0.6367.201
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.common.selenium_manager:chrome 124.0.6367.201 already exists
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.common.selenium_manager:chrome 124.0.6367.201 is available at /home/scaride/.cache/selenium/chrome/linux64/124.0.6367.201/chrome
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.common.selenium_manager:Required driver: chromedriver 124.0.6367.201
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.common.selenium_manager:chromedriver 124.0.6367.201 already in the cache
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.common.selenium_manager:Driver path: /home/scaride/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/124.0.6367.201/chromedriver
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.common.selenium_manager:Browser path: /home/scaride/.cache/selenium/chrome/linux64/124.0.6367.201/chrome
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.common.service:Started executable: `/home/scaride/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/124.0.6367.201/chromedriver` in a child process with pid: 24249 using 0 to output -3
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection:POST http://localhost:46735/session {'capabilities': {'firstMatch': [{}], 'alwaysMatch': {'browserName': 'chrome', 'pageLoadStrategy': <PageLoadStrategy.normal: 'normal'>, 'browserVersion': None, 'goog:chromeOptions': {'extensions': [], 'binary': '/home/scaride/.cache/selenium/chrome/linux64/124.0.6367.201/chrome', 'args': []}}}}
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection:Remote response: status=500 | data={"value":{"error":"session not created","message":"session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.\n  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)\n  (The process started from chrome location /home/scaride/.cache/selenium/chrome/linux64/124.0.6367.201/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)","stacktrace":"#0 0x56122066ee43 \u003Cunknown>\n#1 0x56122035d4e7 \u003Cunknown>\n#2 0x561220391a66 \u003Cunknown>\n#3 0x56122038d9c0 \u003Cunknown>\n#4 0x5612203d67f0 \u003Cunknown>\n#5 0x5612203ca1f3 \u003Cunknown>\n#6 0x56122039b28a \u003Cunknown>\n#7 0x56122039bc5e \u003Cunknown>\n#8 0x56122063316b \u003Cunknown>\n#9 0x5612206370bb \u003Cunknown>\n#10 0x56122061f281 \u003Cunknown>\n#11 0x561220637c22 \u003Cunknown>\n#12 0x56122060413f \u003Cunknown>\n#13 0x56122065df98 \u003Cunknown>\n#14 0x56122065e170 \u003Cunknown>\n#15 0x56122066df94 \u003Cunknown>\n#16 0x7f26a109f609 start_thread\n"}} | headers=HTTPHeaderDict({'Content-Length': '966', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'cache-control': 'no-cache'})
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection:Finished Request
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SessionNotCreatedException                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [4], line 3
      1 from selenium import webdriver
----> 3 driver = webdriver.Chrome()
      4 driver.maximize_window()
      5 url = 'https://www.carrefour.com.ar/almacen'

File ~/.pyenv/versions/taxifare-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py:45, in WebDriver.__init__(self, options, service, keep_alive)
     42 service = service if service else Service()
     43 options = options if options else Options()
---> 45 super().__init__(
     46     browser_name=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME["browserName"],
     47     vendor_prefix="goog",
     48     options=options,
     49     service=service,
     50     keep_alive=keep_alive,
     51 )

File ~/.pyenv/versions/taxifare-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py:66, in ChromiumDriver.__init__(self, browser_name, vendor_prefix, options, service, keep_alive)
     57 executor = ChromiumRemoteConnection(
     58     remote_server_addr=self.service.service_url,
     59     browser_name=browser_name,
   (...)
     62     ignore_proxy=options._ignore_local_proxy,
     63 )
     65 try:
---> 66     super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
     67 except Exception:
     68     self.quit()

File ~/.pyenv/versions/taxifare-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:208, in WebDriver.__init__(self, command_executor, keep_alive, file_detector, options)
    206 self._authenticator_id = None
    207 self.start_client()
--> 208 self.start_session(capabilities)

File ~/.pyenv/versions/taxifare-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:292, in WebDriver.start_session(self, capabilities)
    285 """Creates a new session with the desired capabilities.
    286 
    287 :Args:
    288  - capabilities - a capabilities dict to start the session with.
    289 """
    291 caps = _create_caps(capabilities)
--> 292 response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
    293 self.session_id = response.get("sessionId")
    294 self.caps = response.get("capabilities")

File ~/.pyenv/versions/taxifare-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:347, in WebDriver.execute(self, driver_command, params)
    345 response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    346 if response:
--> 347     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    348     response["value"] = self._unwrap_value(response.get("value", None))
    349     return response

File ~/.pyenv/versions/taxifare-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py:229, in ErrorHandler.check_response(self, response)
    227         alert_text = value["alert"].get("text")
    228     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
--> 229 raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /home/scaride/.cache/selenium/chrome/linux64/124.0.6367.201/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x56122066ee43 <unknown>
#1 0x56122035d4e7 <unknown>
#2 0x561220391a66 <unknown>
#3 0x56122038d9c0 <unknown>
#4 0x5612203d67f0 <unknown>
#5 0x5612203ca1f3 <unknown>
#6 0x56122039b28a <unknown>
#7 0x56122039bc5e <unknown>
#8 0x56122063316b <unknown>
#9 0x5612206370bb <unknown>
#10 0x56122061f281 <unknown>
#11 0x561220637c22 <unknown>
#12 0x56122060413f <unknown>
#13 0x56122065df98 <unknown>
#14 0x56122065e170 <unknown>
#15 0x56122066df94 <unknown>
#16 0x7f26a109f609 start_thread


Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea. Edit your question and add the code/HTML as text, properly formatted.

With Selenium 4.6+, you still need a driver but what's changed is that they added Selenium Manager which takes care of finding the right driver, downloading, and configuring it to be used automatically.
Reduce your startup code to the below and see if that helps.
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
url = "about:blank"
driver.get(url)

The only downside I've seen to this is if your machine doesn't have a connection to the internet. In that case, fetching the driver will fail.

It is not running either Error.

You can look on the page that I linked to see how to check that the driver was successfully downloaded. I would verify that it was downloaded. If it was... I'm not sure what else to suggest.

The error is the following:
Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally. (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist) (The process started from chrome location home/scaride/.cache/selenium/chrome/linux64/124.0.6367.91/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
I already check that  C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is in the PATH environment variables, that the version of Google is in the path it says above.

If you are running the code in my answer, I would suggest that you delete ALL existing instances of chromedriver on your machine and let SeleniumManager download and configure it for you and see if that helps.

I deleted all instances and according to the debug is using the version installed by Selenium Manager. But still is not working. I paste here the error:
